# IOS ASLR address calculation with delta offset (ARM64)

Tags: disassembly, ios, lldb, arm64

I am learning `LLDB` to debug ios apps, I have a jailbroken iPhone IOS 14.3 and a debugserver.

Screenshot of start connect to remote process:

[image: here is a screenshot of start connect to remote process]

Sections of my process(image dump sections hidenseek):

[image: sections of my process]

Next, I calculated the delta at the address from the disassembled unity engine as, `Delta = end of PAGEZERO - start of TEXT`

This is the address of the function where I want to put a breakpoint:

[image: breakpoint]

Hence, `Delta = 0x104a60000 - 0x10000000` = `0x4a60000`

Then I consider the address, it will be equal to `delta + offset` in the disassembler,

[image: **resultant address **]

but it turns out to be an unknown address, I did the same as in the training video.

What am I doing wrong? How to calculate the correct address?

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: `I did the same as in the training video.` Which video?

Comment: https://youtu.be/_i_v6pWqDQQ

Comment: in the video, the situation is approximately the same, but the addresses that I get are completely different from those in the debugger

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237769/lldb-disassemble-functions-at-pointer-location-obj-c-macos), try `disas -a 0x5e409a8`. You might also consider reading [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123105652/https://kov4l3nko.github.io/blog/2016-04-27-debugging-ios-binaries-with-lldb/), the ASLR section (but I don't fully understand his/her command in lldb)

Comment: Most you your screen shots just show terminal content. Such content should better be posted as text. Just copy and paste it into your question and format it as code. Screen shots are bad for readability and also bad if you want later search it as image content can't be searched.

Comment: You can use the "image lookup -a "address" command, it allows you to bypass ASLR and see the address from the disassembler, but I did not find the command to do the same vice versa

Comment: Is the screenshot of the disassembly your own or from the tutorial?  If it is not yours then I imagine you have a different version of Candy Crush to the video and disassembly will almost certainly differ.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a breakpoint using lldb on `func.013e09a8` like this:

```
b -a 0x013e09a8 -s AppExecutableName
```

No manual ASLR calculations required. If you continue in `lldb` with `con` you should see something like:

```
    frame #0: 0x013e19a8 AppExecutableName`___lldb_unnamed_symbol139640$$AppExecutableName
AppExecutableName`___lldb_unnamed_symbol139640$$AppExecutableName:
->  0x013e19a8 <+0>:  stp    x22, x21, [sp, #-0x30]!
    0x013e19ac <+4>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x10]
    0x013e19a0 <+8>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
    0x013e19a4 <+12>: add    x29, sp, #0x20            ; =0x20
```

The formula for ASLR shift is now:

```
p/x 0x013e19a8-0x013e09a8
```

From this point provided your executable doesn't change (presumably by the means of AppStore autoupdate) you can also revisit this function with a symbolic breakpoint if you want to:

```
b ___lldb_unnamed_symbol139640$$AppExecutableName
```

To convert the other way round i.e. the ASLR shifted address to the `0x100000000` base one (suitable for disassembler) use:

```
image lookup -a 0x013e19a8
```